Reference to System.Resources.Tools.StronglyTypedResourceBuilder changed from Version 17 to 15 after Upgrade to .NEt Framework 4.8
I just made an upgrade of a ASP.NET MVC solution from to framework version 4.72 to 4.8. Worked fine so far but I recognized something that seems strange to me:
In several *.Designer.cs files of resources the following line:
[global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Resources.Tools.StronglyTypedResourceBuilder", "17.0.0.0")]

changed to:
[global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Resources.Tools.StronglyTypedResourceBuilder", "15.0.0.0")]

How I understand that: After upgrading the framework, the version of StronglyTypedResourceBuilder was set down to version 15. I did not find anything about that behaviour during research on the web and wondering if this is correct or if I should change the value back to 17 or even something higher?
Maybe anyone faced this too and could tell me something about it. Any hints would be appreciated.
